# WebView showing multiple html pages

Tags: android, jquery, webview

I have a webview that loads a particular html page. The page contains a jQuery ListView. When i click on the list another page should open via the `<a href="">` tag. However this page opens up overlapping the previous page. You can see this in the picture:
(The first one is the normal list. Second picture shows the overlapping):

This is my code in the onCreate method:

```
 myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView3);
 WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
 webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 myWebView.loadUrl(webaddress);
```

I tried to use `myWebView.loadUrl("about:blank")` before i load my actual Url but then everything appears blank.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you used `data-role="page"` in html properly?

Comment: @PurpleDroid yes i have. Its like <body><div data-role="page">........</div></body>

Comment: Just one page in body? Your structure should be `<body><div data-role="page1">........</div><div data-role="page2">........</div>...</body>` Is it proper?

Comment: @PurpleDroid everything is not in one html page. The second picture is another html page on server to which it links to

Comment: Where is the overlap? I don't see an overlap. What I see is a new page with the menu of the old page. Or a new page with the same menu but on the wrong place.

Comment: The menu shouldn't be there. Its not on the new page